Positive operator and invertibility on Hilbert space
If $B(H)$ denotes the set of linear bounded operators, where $H$ be the infinite dimensional Hilbert space, then I have two following questions.
a) If $A,B\in{B(H)},$ where $B$ is invertible and $A^*BA=0,$ then is $A=0$ ?
b) If $B$ is a positive operator, then is $B^{-1}$ positive?
I don't have any idea how to prove or disprove (a). For (b), I have to show that $(B^{-1}x,x) > 0 ~\forall x\in H,$ using $(Bx,x) > 0$. Here (,) represents inner product on $H.$ Kindly help..
THANKS.

Concerning (b), any element $x\neq 0$ can be represented as $x=By$ for some $y\neq 0.$ Hence $$\langle B^{-1}x,x\rangle= \langle y,By\rangle >0$$ The statement (a) is true for $B>0.$ More generally (a)  holds iff the number $0$ does not belong to the numerical range of $B.$ Indeed if $A^*BA=0$ for $A\neq 0$ then the numerical range of $B$ contains $0.$ Conversely, assume   $0$ is in the numerical range of $B,$ i.e.
$\langle Bv,v\rangle=0,$ for some $\|v\|=1.$ Let $A$ be the orthogonal projection onto $v.$ Then for any $x,y$ we get $$\langle A^*BAx,y\rangle =\langle BAx,Ay\rangle =0$$ Hence $A^*BA=0.$
If $B^*=B$ is not a multiple of a positive operator then the numerical range contains $0,$ i.e. (a) fails. Such operator exists if $\dim \mathcal{H}\ge 2.$ For example if $e_n$ is an orthonormal basis let $Be_n=(-1)^ne_n$ and $v=2^{-1/2}(e_1+e_2).$ Then $\langle Bv,v\rangle=0.$

(a) is false. For example, let $H = \mathbb{C}^2$, $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.
For (b), the only way I can think of at the moment uses spectral theorem in some way, in which case it is basically obvious. But maybe the following proof is slightly more elementary: assume you can use the fact that, whenever $B$ is positive, there exists a positive operator $B^{1/2}$ such that $B = B^{1/2} B^{1/2}$. Since $B$ is invertible, $B^{1/2}$ is as well. But then one easily observes that $B^{-1} = (B^{1/2})^{-1} (B^{1/2})^{-1}$. Now, by direct algebraic manipulation, we see that $(A^\ast)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^\ast$ for any invertible $A$, so in particular $A^{-1}$ is self-adjoint whenever $A$ is. Thus, $(B^{1/2})^{-1}$ is self-adjoint, so $\langle B^{-1}x, x \rangle = \langle (B^{1/2})^{-1} (B^{1/2})^{-1} x, x \rangle = \langle (B^{1/2})^{-1} x, (B^{1/2})^{-1} x \rangle \geq 0$.
